# Using nested form to update and create associated items with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I have a order form with restrictions on the number of items you can select that accepts nested attributes and I'd like to perform a `create` and an `update` on it's associated items when I update the order.

My form looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @food_order do |f| %>
    <% @food_order.order_items.each do |oi| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :order_items, oi do |oi_form| %>
            <%= oi_form.input :quantity %>
        <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

My validator looks like:

```
# OrderItem.rb
validate :food_order_quantity

def food_order_quantity
   if (order.limit - order.order_items.sum(:quantity)) < self.quantity
      errors.add(:base, "Too many products.  Please update your cart.")
   end
end
```

Let's imagine I create an order with a limit of 10 items and select 10 items:

```
food_order = FoodOrder.create(limit: 10)
order_item_1 = OrderItem.create(order: food_order, quantity: 10)
```

If I attempt to update the order by reducing `order_item_1`'s quantity by 1 and adding a new `order_item` with a quantity of 1 I get an error even though the total quantity is correct:

```
order_item_1.quantity = 9
order_item_2 = OrderItem.new(order: food_order, quantity: 1)

put client_food_order_path(@client, food_order), params: { 
  food_order: {
    id: food_order.id,
    order_items_attributes: [
      order_item_1.attributes,
      order_item_2.attributes,
    ]
  }
}

# returns the following error
@messages={:"order_items.base"=>["Too many products.  Please update your cart."]}
```

I understand that it's attempting to save `order_item_2` before updating `order_item_1` and in that time, the controller believes there are 11 items (simply because `order_item_1` has not yet been updated).

What can I do to allow this sort of operation?

Comment: What happens if you updated the attributes for `order_item_1` instead of the reassignment without save?

Comment: If I was to update it first, then the call would succeed.  The only issue is that there are  many items being passed at once.  Are you thinking I should update all `order_items` that are already created, and then attempt to create the new ones?

Comment: No, was just curious. Theres a gem, cocoon, that I use for nested relationship forms.

Comment: I'm kind of curious what the real world motivation for this is. It's pretty problematic logic wise. What happens if the limit of an order is updated? That would make all the order items invalid. Also limit is a SQL keyword so not a great name.

Comment: The use case is updating an order that has associated `order_items`.  You can't update a limit ater a `food_order` is submitted.  And I dont actually call it `limit`, I just used that for the example.

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959632/custom-validation-on-nested-attributes